# SharePoint 365 edit page issue

Tags: sharepoint

I am going nuts trying to figure out what is happening here.
I created a new page in a SharePoint site using the gear and clicking add page.

[image: Screen Grab]

The page on the right is the home page for the site and in the red box is the edit and settings for the page.
On the left I have thee new page that I added to the site, and in yellow is the edit box for this page.

How do I make it so that the edit are for the new page works the same way as the right page? What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that comes across this. If you use a "Site Page" you dont get the options. You need to use a different type of page ie "Wiki Page"